# Should I return &Option<Foo> or Option<&Foo> from a getter?

Tags: rust

I have a struct:

```
struct Foo {}
struct Boo {
    foo: Option<Foo>,
}
```

I want to create getter for it, so user cannot modify it but can read it:

```
impl Boo {
    pub fn get_foo(&self) -> ? { unimplemented!(); }
}
```

Should I return `&Option<Foo>` or `Option<&Foo>`? Are there any advantages between these two variants?

I use both variants in my program, and it became an inconvenience to mix them, so I want to choose one of them for the entire program.

Answer (score 11):

Use `Option<&T>` instead of `&Option<T>`. Callers are interested in the wrapped value, not in `Option`.

Also, the common way to implement a getter like this is as follows:

```
impl Boo {
    pub fn get_foo(&self) -> Option<&Foo> { self.foo.as_ref() }
}
```

This way you don't need to check the wrapped value in the getter. If you want to return a mutable value, use `as_mut()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 10):

When in doubt, pick the most flexible solution. This leaves you the most leeway in the future to change the internals of the struct without altering its API.

In this case, this means picking `Option<&T>`:

- `&Option<T>` forces you to have a reference to an option,
- `Option<&T>` only requires a reference to a `T`.

So, for example, in the latter case I could store a `Vec<T>` or a `Result<T, Error>` and still be able to hand out a `Option<&T>`. It is more flexible.

*Note: this is why interfaces generally use `&str` instead of `&String`, `&[T]` instead of `&Vec<T>`, ... more flexibility!*